# How to build a proper restaurant app

Tags: android, servlets

So I am relatively new to Android and programming in general. But i have been tasked with building a restaurant finder app. The app must basically access a database on a server (remote)and populate the screen based with all the restaurants which match the search parameters. I can make the front end and have also the database ready. I am seriously struggling with the connectivity between the 2. Could anyone suggest the approach i Should take and thus the resources i need to code it? I'm still a novice coder so am struggling with coding the servlets,etc.

Comment: but what part of code u r struggling? any code u can show?

Comment: And what database is it? Have you considered using `Parse.com` for your database?

Comment: Using HTTPSocket ans JSON should do what you want. You need the server providing the database, and app works as client. the data transfer is done with JSON

Comment: @newbie have a look at my NFC HOTEL app [here](https://github.com/saijaddhuka/NFCHotel) this could be good starting point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making restaurant finder app , Follow following instructions like

Make sure that web services are ready (mainly JSON or XMl)
then fetch them using either
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ 
or 
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/
turtorial

and show them in list or on Google maps (For Google maps you need latitude and longitude of particular restaurant )